# How to isolate the fourth line in a print output?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, beautifulsoup, printing

I have a screen scraper that prints prices like this

Input:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,"lxml")
for item in soup.select('.valueValue-3kA0oJs5'):
    [elem.extract() for elem in soup("div")]
    print(item.text)
```

Output:

```
478.40
482.11
476.45
480.62
480.62

+5.15 (+1.08%)
```

I only want it to print the fourth(or fifth) line, in this case 480.62

I have tried this:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,"lxml")
for item in soup.select('.valueValue-3kA0oJs5'):
    [elem.extract() for elem in soup("div")]
    my_str = str(item.text, end=" ")
    price_list = my_str.split()
    price_list[3]
```

But that gives this error:

```
---> 33    my_str = str(item.text, end=" ")
34         price_list = my_str.split()
35         price_list[3]

TypeError: 'end' is an invalid keyword argument for str()
```

btw: , end=" " puts everything next to each other, my_str.split() seperates them by space and with price_list[3] I tried to isolate the fourth one.

Does anyone knows how to do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I am a bit confused as you are not saving the output of the list comprehension ```[elem.extract() for elem in soup("div")]```. Is the ```print(item.text)``` independent of that line of code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to concatenate them to a string, which won't work with the syntax you used as you would just overwrite it at each iteration, you could use a temporary list to store the elements:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,"lxml")
price_list= []
for item in soup.select('.valueValue-3kA0oJs5'):
    [elem.extract() for elem in soup("div")]
    price_list.append(item.text)
    
print(price_list[3])
```

Note, that the printing command is dedented. You only want to do it once the loop is complete and you have the complete price list.

Comment: if I run that it says  
---> 34         print(price_list[3])

IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: In that case, you have less than 4 items in this table. Print the complete list before selecting an item to check what was stored.
If you want it to always work, you might need to check for the length of the list before trying to print anything. Just use an if-statement.

Comment: yes the full price_list is in this case like this: ['']
['478.40']
['482.97']
['476.45']
['481.77']
['481.77']
['']
['+6.30 (+1.33%)']

Comment: This is not a list. These are several lists. Can you please edit the original post to show the new code? I suspect you might have an indentation mistake.